# Android: The specified child already has a parent issue

Tags: android

I am getting this error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

From the following code:

**MyActivity.java**

```
public void displayTable(){//This is method to display table
        List<Integer> lstIds = helper.getAllTimeOffID(); // it will fetch number of records
        for(int id:lstIds){
            //for each record i am generationg single row(LinearLayout[horizontal])
            TimeOff timeOff = helper.getTimeOffInfo(id);//this is model class for each record
            lstAllTimeOff.add(timeOff); // adding to list for future purpose(no need for this mithod)
            int pxs = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.generalTextSize);
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            LinearLayout viewTimeOffDetailsArea = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.viewTimeOffDetailsArea);
            LinearLayout viewSingleRow = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()); //new row generating
            LayoutParams singleRowParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            viewSingleRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            TextView lblSingleRowDetail = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            TextView lblSingleRowDate = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            TextView lblSingleRowHours = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            ImageButton imgbtnSingleRowAction = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            viewSingleRow.removeAllViews();
            lblSingleRowDetail.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3f));
            lblSingleRowDate.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f));
            lblSingleRowHours.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            lblSingleRowDetail.setTextSize(pxs);
            lblSingleRowDate.setTextSize(pxs);
            lblSingleRowHours.setTextSize(pxs);
            lblSingleRowDetail.setText(timeOff.getTimeOffDetail());
            lblSingleRowDate.setText(timeOff.getTimeOffDate());
            lblSingleRowHours.setText(timeOff.getTimeOffHours());
            imgbtnSingleRowAction.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            imgbtnSingleRowAction.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete1);
            imgbtnSingleRowAction.setId(timeOff.getId());

            viewSingleRow.addView(lblSingleRowDetail);//add label
            viewSingleRow.addView(lblSingleRowDate);//add label
            viewSingleRow.addView(lblSingleRowHours);//add label
            viewSingleRow.addView(imgbtnSingleRowAction);//add image button
            //add whole row into vertical Linear Layout which is in Scroll View
            viewTimeOffDetailsArea.addView(lblSingleRowDetail); //on this line i am getting Error

        }
```

and this is my xml file where i am trying to draw ma rows one by one

**my_xml.xml**

```
  <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollDiv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/viewTimeOffDetailsFooter"
        android:layout_below="@id/lowerSeparator" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewTimeOffDetailsArea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why -1 can you please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `viewSingleRow.addView(lblSingleRowDetail);` and then `viewTimeOffDetailsArea.addView(lblSingleRowDetail);` it causes exception. You can add view only to one parent.

Comment: @GreenRobo sure, what's the problem?

Comment: You can see that int lblSingleRowDetail, lblSingleRowDate & lblSingleRowHours i've provide a weight property, but when data is too long in lblSingleRowDetail then it expands more then weight. now i am using setMaxEms() for that.  ell me if you have any better solution. Thanks

Comment: If I understood you right, setting layout_width of each TextView to 0dp will help. Actually (just advice), it seems that listview will be much better in this situation than your approach.

Comment: after that i thought to stick with setMaxEms() only... its working as expected so... thank you so much by the way